# Terminal Emulator with CTRL+Scroll Zoom

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal-emulator, terminal-multiplexer

Are there any Linux Terminal Emulators that offer "control & scroll zoom" (allowing you to adjust the visible size of fonts by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> and scrolling your mouse-wheel)?

Recently on Windows I discovered [ConEMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConEmu), which offers this feature and I'd love to enjoy it on my Linux desktops too.

Looks like [Terminator](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator/+bug/1435630) is "going" to have this soon! Anything have it now?

Comment: Terminator did add this feature shortly after I posed this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Konsole](https://konsole.kde.org/) has this feature by default.

I would like to know if any others did too, as it's a feature I use regularly to ease readablity.